# Convert regular AdSense units into responsive ones in an easy way

Tags: responsive-design, adsense

I am changing the HTML design of my website, converting all the pages into responsive ones. I am also planning the conversion of the AdSense units of the pages into responsive ones, and wondered if the transformation is as easy as the following.

This is the piece of code of one of the current AdSense units:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
google_ad_slot = "YYYYYYY";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="">
</script>
```

Would it be as easy as adding the 'data-ad-format', removing the 'google_ad_width' and 'google_ad_height', and leaving the information of 'data-ad-client' and 'data-ad-slot'?

```
<script async src="//"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:block"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
data-ad-slot="YYYYYYY"
data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I mean, I do not want to remove my current custom channels and create new ones, and wondered if they would work with a new responsive design.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Info about `YYYYYYY`unit (with `google_ad_width = 300` and `google_ad_height = 250`) is stored on the AdSense side, on AdSense servers, as `"size":"SIZE_300_250"`.

(In my understanding scenario is:

1. with `google_ad_width = 300` and `google_ad_height = 250`, their
   script `show_ads.js` (or `adsbygoogle.js`) can quickly reserve 300x250 space for ad unit
   `YYYYYYY`
2. which will be returned by
   `http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads` as
   `"size":"SIZE_300_250"`.)

Responsive [ad units must be **created** as "responsive"](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en). (And in that case they'll be `"size":"RESPONSIVE"`.)

(The AdSense platform has been, and is being, continually updated and refined, and I *think* they are sanitizing some bad requests now. But, relying on that is potentially risky - even if you see that your ad code modification works, that doesn't mean that it is safe to use. Only a [limited set of modifications](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736) is allowed in AdSense and what you described is **not** one of them.)

> I mean, I do not want to remove my current custom channels and create
>   new ones, and wondered if they would work with a new responsive
>   design.

When you create new responsive units you'll add them to [custom **channels**](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65083) you already have. There is no need to remove existing custom channels.

(If you mean "*I do not want to remove my current **ad units** and create new ones*", then I'm afraid you don't have other choice: standard ad unit can't be "converted" to responsive.)

**Disclaimer**: I can't quote relevant source for what I said above about AdSense ad serving scenario. What I said is based on my ten years experience of being an AdSense publisher, and few years RS and TC on the AdSense Help Forum. On that forum you can see cases of disabled accounts and ad serving [because of code modification](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adsense/This$20includes$20resizing$20ad$20frames$20to$20cut$20off$20parts$20of$20ads).)

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it's not possible. You have to create a new tag.
Hint: You can use *vertical*, *horizontal* and *auto* for the *data-ad-format* attribute (e.g. data-ad-format="auto").